# adding an image into a hyperlink does not show the image in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");

img.setAttribute('src', 'close.png');
img.setAttribute('alt', 'cancel this file');
img.setAttribute('title', 'cancel this file');

var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', '#');

link.appendChild(img);
```

But the result does not show the image?

Did I do anything wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added the link to the document?

Comment: It works now, the link it not correct :D

Comment: @devn: in that case, you might want to delete your question or post your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the path was wrong, it should be:

img.setAttribute('src', 'img/close.png');

Answer (score 0):

You might have to insert the link element you created into the DOM. Currently your link is living in memory and does not exist in the DOM